# When is a number converted to exponential notation via .toString()?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently in the process of investigating a small possible bug/unexpected behavior in NodeJS.

The investigation includes the conversion of numbers to strings via `.toString()`.
I've noticed that for n which satisfies `n <= 1e21 (roughly)`, n is converted to a number with the full form (say `999999999999999900000`), but starting from around `n === 1e21`, the `.toString()` method return exponential/scientific notation (a * 10 ^ b).

This seems consistent with all JS environments I've tested (Node, Chrome, Firefox).

I thought it might be related to `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` But there doesn't seem to be any link.

Where is this threshold defined? What is the actual threshold and why is it this number?

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8.1

Comment: @FabioAntunes Thanks, found it just a few minutes ago, see my answer below

Comment: Oh sorry didn't notice it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more digging, It seems like this is defined in the [ECMAScript Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type).

> a number will be rendered in exponential format if and only if the number's absolute value is greater than or equal to 10^21 or strictly smaller than 10^-6.
> -(CRice)

Full ECMA spec quote:

> 7.1.12.1 ToString Applied to the Number Type The abstract operation
>
> ToString converts a Number m to String format as follows:
>
> 1. If m is NaN, return the String "NaN".
> 2. If m is +0 or −0, return the String "0".
> 3. If m is less than zero, return the String concatenation of the String "-" and ToString(−m).
> 4. If m is +∞, return the String "Infinity".
> 5. Otherwise, let n, k, and s be integers such that k ≥ 1, 10k−1 ≤ s < 10k, the Number value for s × 10n−k is m, and k is as small as
>    possible. Note that k is the number of digits in the decimal
>    representation of s, that s is not divisible by 10, and that the least
>    significant digit of s is not necessarily uniquely determined by these
>    criteria.
> 6. If k ≤ n ≤ 21, return the String consisting of the code units of the k
>    digits of the decimal representation of s (in order, with no leading
>    zeroes), followed by n−k occurrences of the code unit 0x0030 (DIGIT
>    ZERO).
> 7. If 0 < n ≤ 21, return the String consisting of the code units
>    of the most significant n digits of the decimal representation of s,
>    followed by the code unit 0x002E (FULL STOP), followed by the code
>    units of the remaining k−n digits of the decimal representation of s.
> 8. If −6 < n ≤ 0, return the String consisting of the code unit 0x0030
>    (DIGIT ZERO), followed by the code unit 0x002E (FULL STOP), followed
>    by −n occurrences of the code unit 0x0030 (DIGIT ZERO), followed by
>    the code units of the k digits of the decimal representation of s.
> 9. Otherwise, if k = 1, return the String consisting of the code unit of
>    the single digit of s, followed by code unit 0x0065 (LATIN SMALL
>    LETTER E), followed by the code unit 0x002B (PLUS SIGN) or the code
>    unit 0x002D (HYPHEN-MINUS) according to whether n−1 is positive or
>    negative, followed by the code units of the decimal representation of
>    the integer abs(n−1) (with no leading zeroes).
> 10. Return the String
>     consisting of the code units of the most significant digit of the
>     decimal representation of s, followed by code unit 0x002E (FULL STOP),
>     followed by the code units of the remaining k−1 digits of the decimal
>     representation of s, followed by code unit 0x0065 (LATIN SMALL LETTER
>     E), followed by code unit 0x002B (PLUS SIGN) or the code unit 0x002D
>     (HYPHEN-MINUS) according to whether n−1 is positive or negative,
>     followed by the code units of the decimal representation of the
>     integer abs(n−1) (with no leading zeroes).

Comment: You seem to have left out the important part? Item 9 and 10 in that list are the ones which describe the conditions under which exponential notation is used (provided none of the prior criteria were met).

Comment: You also left off the part that defines k, n and s

Comment: You guys are correct, I'm including the entire item.

Comment: Also, since the spec is not so easy to read, I'd note that the conditions for rendering the number in exponential format boil down to: a number will be rendered in exponential format if and only if *the number's absolute value is greater than or equal to 10^21 or strictly smaller than 10^-6*.

Comment: @CRice also correct, I've added your quote to the top of the answer.